# Apex dataloader issue: export apex class

Tags: apex

any one have any idea about export or insert apex class or trigger using data loader?

Please share.

Comment: insert apex class using data loader? what you trying to do? are you trying to deploy one org artifacts to another org ? if you want to create apex class then use  any development IDE for creating apex classes

Comment: actually I have forund apex class,apex trigger, even profile,object permissions also in object list of apex data loader. i have no idea about it also.. I am not sure what can I do with those. I have to test it.

Comment: That's not really an issue with the data loader as much as it is beyond the scope of what the tool was designed to do.

Comment: then what can we do using this. Then is it possible to insert an apex class OR trigger  from one org to another org using data loader? if so then will it execute test class??

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The data loader only exports *data*, not metadata. Use the Migration Toolkit, the Force.com IDE, or any other code that uses the metadata API to extract these classes.

Comment: But you can actually find apex class, apex trigger in the object list of data loader. Not sure what can be done using those

Comment: Exporting these Sobjects shows you data about these records. Each class or a trigger is a record entry in the Apex Class or Apex Trigger Sobjects. Some of the fields from the Apex Trigger export are: ID
NAMESPACEPREFIX
NAME
TABLEENUMORID
USAGEBEFOREINSERT
USAGEAFTERINSERT
USAGEBEFOREUPDATE
USAGEAFTERUPDATE
USAGEBEFOREDELETE
USAGEAFTERDELETE
USAGEISBULK
USAGEAFTERUNDELETE
APIVERSION
STATUS
ISVALID
BODYCRC
BODY
LENGTHWITHOUTCOMMENTS
CREATEDDATE
CREATEDBYID
LASTMODIFIEDDATE
LASTMODIFIEDBYID
SYSTEMMODSTAMP